# Search custom field by name

Tags: custom-fields

if I want to get a value of a custom field, now I have to use `custom_xx`, like this:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getvalue', [
   'return' => "custom_11",
   'id' => 123,
]);
```

As `return` I'd like to use the name of field (`civicrm_custom_field.name`) instead of id. Is it possibile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [api 4](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/usage/) if you want to use as the name

```
$contacts = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'get', [
  'select' => [
    'constituent_information.Most_Important_Issue',
  ],
  'where' => [
    ['id', '=', 123],
  ],
]);
```